# C# 5 and .Net 4.5 - Compiler tricks or library support?

Tags: c#, .net

I have read a lot about async/await being implemented (internally) as a state machine, and would like to know if I can use the VS2012 compiler, while still using Net version 4 as my runtime to use these new features?

I remember that I could do this with several new features of Net 4 while still using Net 3.5 but with the VS2010 compiler.

Thanks,
Martin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right from the Visual Studio Asynchronous programming page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx

> If your Visual Studio 2012 project needs to target Silverlight 5 or
>   .NET Framework 4.0, you can use the Async language support by
>   downloading the [Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=250980). This
>   pack is not required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET
>   for Windows apps.

So yes, you can download the Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012 and use the async programming features while still targeting .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Can you tell me if this package is just for 'syntax support' or if all the Net 4.5 extension methods are available.